# Let $R$ be a UFD and $a,b,c \in R$ be nonzero. If $c \mid ab$ and $\gcd(a, c) = 1$, then $c \mid b$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Here is the problem
If $c\ |\ ab$ and $\text{gcd}(a,c)=1$ then $c\ |\ b$
Here's my approach. There exists $x,y$ such that $ax+cy=1$, so $c\ |\ axb+cyb=b$
I'm pretty sure my first step is wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: Note $c|axb+cyb \Leftrightarrow c|(ab)x$

Comment: @Kai Bézout's Identity i.e. $ax + cd = 1$ fails in arbitrary UFDs. You cannot use that result.

Answer (score 4):

It is not true that $\gcd(a, c) = 1$ implies that there exist $x, y \in R$ with $ax + cy = 1$. (For example when $R = \mathbb Z[X]$, $a = 2$, $c = X$.)

Instead work with the factorizations of $a, b, c$ into irreducibles.

Comment: Oh! Yeah, so all irreducible factors of $c$ doesn't divide $a$, so by definition of UFD, they divide $b$. Is that right?

Comment: Indeed. All prime _powers_ dividing $c$ divide $b$.